# Information about permutation character from local action

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups, character-theory

Let $G$ be a finite permutation group acting transitively, but not regularly, on a set $V$. Let $H$ be the stabilizer of some point $v\in V$, and suppose that $H$ acts 2-transitively on one of its (non-trivial) orbits, i.e. $H$ acts 2-transitively on the (left) cosets of $H\cap H^g$ for an appropriate choice of $g\in G$.

> General question: What can I conclude about the permutation character of $G$ acting on $V$?

Specifically:

- Can I give a lower bound for the multiplicities of the non-trivial irreducible components of the permutation character of $G$ on $V$?
- What about the dimensions of these components?
- What about if I weaken '2-transitively' to 'primitively' or something similar?

Comment: Look at the case where the action of G is 3-transitive. Then a 
point stabilizer is 2-transitive on its (unique) nontrivial
orbit.  In this case the permutation character of G is the sum of
the principal character and one other irreducible, so the (unique)
nontrivial irreducible constituent has multiplicity 1. Thus 1 is
the best possible lower bound on the multiplicities. That's not
very interesting, so I wonder if the first question contains an
error, and "upper bound" is intended in place of "lower bound"